LLVM extract function source paths from static library
I am building the following code snippet into a static library.
#[no_mangle]
#[inline(never)]
pub extern "C" fn my_other_function() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
}



#[no_mangle]
#[inline(never)]
pub extern "C" fn my_super_cool_function() {
    my_other_function()
}

I would like to locate the source files / line numbers from the static library to pass to my debugger. The goal is to get something that looks like this.
my_other_function PATH_TO_SOURCE_FILE:3
my_super_cool_function PATH_TO_SOURCE_FILE:11

Is it possible to extract source file info from a static lib?
Using objdump, I can locate the function symbols and extract the plain text source as well, but I cannot seem to locate the original source files containing the symbols.
objdump --source PATH_TO_A.a

Disassembly of section __TEXT,__text:

0000000000000000 <_my_other_function>:
; pub extern "C" fn my_other_function() {
       0: 55                            pushq   %rbp
       1: 48 89 e5                      movq    %rsp, %rbp
       4: 48 83 ec 30                   subq    $48, %rsp
;     println!("Hello, world!");
       8: 48 8d 7d d0                   leaq    -48(%rbp), %rdi
       c: 48 8d 35 00 00 00 00          leaq    (%rip), %rsi            ## 0x13 <_my_other_function+0x13>
      13: ba 01 00 00 00                movl    $1, %edx
      18: e8 00 00 00 00                callq   0x1d <_my_other_function+0x1d>
      1d: 48 8d 7d d0                   leaq    -48(%rbp), %rdi
      21: e8 00 00 00 00                callq   0x26 <_my_other_function+0x26>
; }
      26: 48 83 c4 30                   addq    $48, %rsp
      2a: 5d                            popq    %rbp
      2b: c3                            retq
      2c: 0f 1f 40 00                   nopl    (%rax)

Full contents gets close too, I can find file paths but no symbols or line numbers.
objdump --full-contents PATH_TO_A.a
Contents of section __DWARF,__debug_line:
 0380 4c000000 02002100 00000101 fb0e0d00  L.....!.........
 0390 01010101 00000001 00000173 72630000  ...........src..
 03a0 6c69622e 72730001 00000000 09020000  lib.rs..........
 03b0 00000000 00001405 050a8305 020b08c9  ................
 03c0 0500a405 050a4b05 020b5902 02000101  ......K...Y.....


The information is encoded in binary using the DWARF Format, so you would need to parse that to get the relationship between function and file locations.
